# Custom map (JSON) won't display on Power BI dashboard

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

This is a power BI Desktop query.
I've been trying to add a custom map in shape map.

The custom map I'm trying to use is the world-countries-san-anartica.json found here: https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson

And the dataset am working on is the Sovereign states and dependencies by population table in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population

When I click Format -> Shape -> Add Map and upload the custom map, I still see the USA: states (default) map in my dashboard and not the custom map.

How would I fix this?
Thanks!